# UITableViewCells won't change color when tapped on

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to make a "Change theme" option in my application. For some reason, this code will always somehow make it so that when I tap on the cell, for instance if I tap on "Dark Theme" on my app when it is currently light theme, all my code fires and the navigationbar goes dark gray, my tableview background becomes the color it is supposed to be, etc however the "Light Theme" stays in light mode. It will still keep the white background and black text unless i go back into my settings viewcontroller and reenter "ChangeThemeViewController". I am stumped, ive been trying for hours to fix this. Anyone know why it does this and how I can fix it? Here is my code.

```
#import "ChangeThemeViewController.h"

@interface ChangeThemeViewController ()

@end

@implementation ChangeThemeViewController {

    NSArray *tableData;
    NSInteger theme;
    NSString *simpleTableIdentifier;
    UITableViewCell *cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSInteger theme = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                       integerForKey:@"theme"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:theme forKey:@"theme"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    //add variable for theme here
//    if (theme == 0) {
//        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
//
//        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil;
//        _tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;
//        [self.navigationController.navigationBar
//         setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}];
//    }
//
//
//    if (theme == 1) {
//        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//
//        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
//        _tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
//        [self.navigationController.navigationBar
//         setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
//    }
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Light Theme", @"Dark Theme", nil];

}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        //add variable for theme here
        NSInteger theme = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                           integerForKey:@"theme"];
        if (theme == 0) {
            NSLog(@"theme is 0, running cellforrowindexpath");
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = nil;
            tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
        }
        if (theme == 1) {
            NSLog(@"theme is 1, running cellforrowindexpath");
            UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:30/255.0
                                             green:30/255.0
                                              blue:30/255.0
                                             alpha:1];
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            tableView.backgroundColor = color;
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:0];

            }
            if (indexPath.row == 1) {
                cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:1];
            }
        }

       }

    return cell;
}
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:theme forKey:@"theme"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSInteger theme = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"theme"];
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
            NSLog(@"row 0 picked should change into light mode");
            theme = 0;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:theme forKey:@"theme"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

            self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil;
            _tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar
             setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}];
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = nil;




        }


        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
            NSLog(@"row 1 picked should change into dark mode");
            theme = 1;

            self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:theme forKey:@"theme"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:30/255.0
                                             green:30/255.0
                                              blue:30/255.0
                                             alpha:1];
            self.tableView.backgroundColor = color;

            self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            _tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar
             setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];






        }


    if (theme == 0) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    if (theme == 1) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    }







- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change tableView cell properties from didSeleteRowAtIndexPath. Reload the tableView and put condition of cellDesign in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Below is a suggestion-

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSInteger theme = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"theme"];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
       theme = 0;
    }else if (indexPath.row ==1){
       theme = 1;
    }
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:theme forKey:@"theme"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self changeTheme:theme];
     [tableView reloadData];
 }
-(void)changeTheme:(NSInteger)theme{
   if(theme==0){
     // do necessary changes for theme =0 for View Controller except cells
   }else{
     // do necessary changes for theme =1 for View Controller except cells
   }
}
```